# Data virtualization and sorting, with editing and validation

Tags: validation, sorting, uwp, virtualization

Are there any solutions out there for sorting with data virtualization? The use case is a large set 
of transactions sorted in any of several ways. Editing a transaction puts it out of order, saving it may move the transaction to a different page. By itself that is not so bad, however (a) it has to work with a validation system and (b) other entries can be added or edited prior to the save, resulting in an increasingly disordered list.

One solution that I think wouldn't work very well would be to resort each dirty page (e.g. right after the save)I because that would significantly increase the number of entries notified to the list view, resulting in flicker.

Comment: The -4 is a bit discouraging. Maybe I didn't ask the question very clearly. This isn't a particularly easy question.

Comment: Using random access data virtualization, obviously you have to reload when a different sort order is chosen. That's not the question here. The question is what to do when editing the data. If you change the sort field in a record, then it can re-sort onto a different page. I don't want to reload just due to an edit of one record. Consequently one page shrinks while another one grows (assuming the destination page is in memory). It starts to get hard when several records can be edited before any of them are saved. The validation aspect is just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your question. Maybe, you want to sort your collection on your ItemsControl. There should be some third-party controls can achieve your target.

For example, [DataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdatagrid/getting-started) in Syncfusion.

The SfDataGrid control for Universal Windows Platform is used to display collection of data in rows and columns. It includes editing and data shaping features (Sorting, grouping, filtering and etc) that allows the end users to easily manage the data.

Comment: Well, I meant publicly available rather than proprietary solutions.
I don't want to load all the data and then sort it in the UI, because the data is too large to load in one go.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was to only use a single virtual page. With just one page you can more easily manage the relocation of edited entries, since you won't have to move them between pages or deal with them falling in between pages. New entities can be kept at the bottom of the collection until they are saved. Having only one page also improves the chances of detecting concurrency errors.

Note this question was not primarily about re-sorting, it was more about maintaining a sort order during edits.

The DataGrid suggestion does not suit the situation, I need free-form templates rather than a grid.

Validation, concurrency, and the need for batch edits just make it a bit harder.